# how to change the ICON of Jquery button

Tags: css, jquery-ui, html

I want to use CSS Sprites images (img-64x64.png) to replace Icon of Jquery button.
where is wrong the following my code? Thanks!

```
// CSS Sprites Images
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-icon {
        background-image: url(img/img-64x64.png);
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
    }
    //Image A
    .ui-icon-A {
        background-position: -448px 0px;
    }
    //Image B
    .ui-icon-B {
        background-position: -128px 0px;
    }      
</style>   

// JQuery code
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        InitBtnIcon();
    });
// Init Button
function InitBtnIcon()
{
    //Create Button A
    $("#btnIconA").button({
        icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-A'      
               }
    });
//Create Button B
$("#btnIconB").button({
    icons: {
            primary: 'ui-icon-B'      
           }
    });
}
</script>
//Html code       
<div>
<button id="btnIconA">Button Icon</button>
<button id="btnIconB">Button Icon</button>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change icons to the buttons on a jQuery UI Button? I've tried doing it this way. Who can give me some advice about my code, Thanks!

Comment: Never used JQ UI, but is your UI CSS loaded AFTER your custom css? Or what is your exact problem? No icons? Still standard icons?

Comment: No any icon shows on Button. I don't know how to code for CSS Sprites.

Comment: If only use <button> with background-img, can show icon on button. I want to make the icon locates center of button, so I use JQ UI Button icon .  Thanks!

Comment: C++ style comments aren't valid in HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your sample code I was missing the img-64x64.png, but depending on when you load the CSS code you could add the !important keyword. Ex:

```
.ui-icon {
    background-image: url(img/img-64x64.png) !important;
    width: 64px !important;
    height: 64px !important;
}
```